# Import report to CRM2011 beta

Tags: dynamics-crm, report, dynamics-crm-2011

I used Sql Server report builder to build a report, then i exported this report as  rdl file. The question is how to import it to the reports in CRM2011 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Got it, Just point to from file in the report wizard. Sorry for that !